# Ao gerar uma imagem, quero apenas visualiza-la e não salva-la

Tags: java, imagem

Ao usar esse codigo eu salvo a imagem, mas em vez de salvar eu quero apenas visualiza-la.

```
String key = "Lucão MC";
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("recibo.png"));

    Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial Regular", Font.PLAIN, 55));
    graphics.drawString(key, 300, 300);
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("recibo1.png"));
    System.out.println("Image Created");
```

Comment: Onde deseja visualizar?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Pelo que estiver padrão no windows.

Comment: Você quer abrir uma janela com a imagem (no Swing), é isso, certo?

Comment: Sim, de preferencia com o visualizador padrão do windows.

Comment: Pra usar o visualizador padrão do Windows, use a resposta do colega Dilnei (apensar de que você vai ter que salvar o arquivo antes). Se quiser usar uma forma genérica (que funciona em qualquer SO), use a minha resposta. P.S.: Na próxima vez que perguntar, siga estes dois conselhos: 1) seja específico, pois assim vc evita que as pessoas percam tempo e agiliza a sua ajuda; 2) prepare um [mcve], pois nem todo mundo tem boa vontade de pegar seu código e tentar arrumar pra compilar.

Comment: Tudo bem, valeu pelas dicas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a classe [Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) do awt, ex:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\images\\suaImage.jpg"));
```

Comment: Examente, no caso quero apenas visualizar, sem salvar.

Comment: Desculpe Dilnei. O AP foi confuso. Aparentemente ele queria usar o visualizador externo do Windows, e portanto a sua resposta é válida (até ganhou o meu +1). :)

Comment: sem problemas, a sua é tão válida quanto a minha, afinal ele quer fazer in memory :)

Answer (score 3):

Crie um `JFrame`, dentro dele adicione um `JLabel` e defina o conteúdo do label como uma imagem usando um `ImageIcon` encapsulando o seu `BufferedImage`. Exemplo:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String key = "Lucão MC";
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("recibo.png"));

        Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial Regular", Font.PLAIN, 55));
        graphics.drawString(key, 300, 300);

        //ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("recibo1.png"));
        Teste.showImage(bufferedImage);

        System.out.println("Image Created");


    }

    // Esse método é o que exibe a imagem em uma janela
    protected static void showImage(BufferedImage img) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```